# Count types for every time difference from the time of one specific type within a time range with a granularity of one second in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, time-series, data-analysis, olap

I have the following time-series data in a `DataFrame` in [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/):

***`(id, timestamp, type)`***

- the `id` column can be any integer value and many rows of the same id
  can exist in the table
- the `timestamp` column is a timestamp represented by an integer (for simplification)
- the `type` column is a string type variable where each distinct
  string on the column represents one category. One special category
  out of all is **'A'**

My question is the following:

Is there any way to compute (with SQL or pyspark DataFrame operations):

**the counts of every type
for all the time differences from the timestamp corresponding to all the rows
of type='A' within a time range (e.g. [-5,+5]), with granularity of 1 second**

For example, for the following `DataFrame`:

```
ts_df = sc.parallelize([
    (1,'A',100),(2,'A',1000),(3,'A',10000),

    (1,'b',99),(1,'b',99),(1,'b',99),
    (2,'b',999),(2,'b',999),(2,'c',999),(2,'c',999),(1,'d',999),
    (3,'c',9999),(3,'c',9999),(3,'d',9999),

    (1,'b',98),(1,'b',98),
    (2,'b',998),(2,'c',998),
    (3,'c',9998)
]).toDF(["id","type","ts"])
ts_df.show()
```

```
+---+----+-----+
| id|type|   ts|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   A|  100|
|  2|   A| 1000|
|  3|   A|10000|
|  1|   b|   99|
|  1|   b|   99|
|  1|   b|   99|
|  2|   b|  999|
|  2|   b|  999|
|  2|   c|  999|
|  2|   c|  999|
|  1|   d|  999|
|  3|   c| 9999|
|  3|   c| 9999|
|  3|   d| 9999|
|  1|   b|   98|
|  1|   b|   98|
|  2|   b|  998|
|  2|   c|  998|
|  3|   c| 9998|
+---+----+-----+
```

for a time difference of **-1** second the result should be:

```
# result for time difference = -1 sec
# b: 5
# c: 4
# d: 2
```

while for a time difference of **-2** seconds the result should be:

```
# result for time difference = -2 sec
# b: 3
# c: 2
# d: 0
```

and so on so forth for any time difference within a time range for a granularity of 1 second.

I tried many different ways by using mostly `groupBy` but nothing seems to work.

I am mostly having difficulties on how to express the time difference from each row of type=`A` even if I have to do it for one specific time difference.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

If I only have to do it for one specific time difference `time_difference` then I could do it with the following way:

```
time_difference = -1
df_type_A = ts_df.where(F.col("type")=='A').selectExpr("ts as fts")
res = df_type_A.join(ts_df, on=df_type_A.fts+time_difference==ts_df.ts)\
.drop("ts","fts").groupBy(F.col("type")).count()
```

The the returned `res` DataFrame will give me exactly what I want for one specific time difference. I create a loop and solve the problem by repeating the same query over and over again.

However, is there any more efficient way than that?

**EDIT2 (solution)**
So that's how I did it at the end:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([
    (1,'b',99),(1,'b',99),(1,'b',99),
    (2,'b',999),(2,'b',999),(2,'c',999),(2,'c',999),(2,'d',999),
    (3,'c',9999),(3,'c',9999),(3,'d',9999),

    (1,'b',98),(1,'b',98),
    (2,'b',998),(2,'c',998),
    (3,'c',9998)
]).toDF(["id","type","ts"])
df1.show()

df2 = sc.parallelize([
    (1,'A',100),(2,'A',1000),(3,'A',10000),
]).toDF(["id","type","ts"]).selectExpr("id as fid","ts as fts","type as ftype")
df2.show()

df3 = df2.join(df1, on=df1.id==df2.fid).withColumn("td", F.col("ts")-F.col("fts"))
df3.show()

df4 = df3.groupBy([F.col("type"),F.col("td")]).count()
df4.show()
```

Will update performance details as soon as I'll have any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this problem would be:

- Divide existing data-frames in two data-frames - with A and without A
- Add a new column in without A df, which is sum of "ts" and time_difference
- Join both data frame, group By and count.

Here is a code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
time_difference = 1
ts_df_A = (
    ts_df
    .filter(ts_df["type"] == "A")
    .drop("id")
    .drop("type")
)

ts_df_td = (
    ts_df
    .withColumn("ts_plus_td", lit(ts_df['ts'] + time_difference))
    .filter(ts_df["type"] != "A")
    .drop("ts")
)

joined_df = ts_df_A.join(ts_df_td, ts_df_A["ts"] == ts_df_td["ts_plus_td"])
agg_df = joined_df.groupBy("type").count()

>>> agg_df.show()
+----+-----+
|type|count|
+----+-----+
|   d|    2|
|   c|    4|
|   b|    5|
+----+-----+

>>>
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Thanks,
Hussain Bohra

Comment: Thank you Hussain,
This is great!
It actually seems to be equivalent to what I have in my EDIT above.
However, (inspired by your solution) I was wondering whether it would be possible to build a column, where we could store the time difference of each row of any type to the corresponding row of type='A' with the same id.
If we could have such a column, then it would be possible to add it on the final group by and get the result of any time difference efficiently. Would that make sense?

Comment: I was thinking something more like this:
```
df1 = # df without type=='A'

# df2 is the dataframe with only type=='A'
df2 = sc.parallelize([
    (1,'A',100),(2,'A',1000),(3,'A',10000),
]).toDF(["id","type","ts"]).selectExpr("id as fid","ts as fts","type as ftype")
df2.show()

and dataframe with new column with the time differences
df2.join(df1, on=df1.id==df2.fid).withColumn("td", F.col("ts")-F.col("fts")).show()
```
And then we can add on the groupby the time difference.

Comment: I also wrote similar type of code for this: 
```ts_df_A = (
 ts_df
 .filter(ts_df["type"] == "A")
 .select(
  col("id").alias("Aid"), 
  col("type").alias("Atype"), 
  col("ts").alias("Ats"))
)

ts_df_td = (
 ts_df
 .withColumn("ts_plus_td", lit(ts_df['ts'] + time_difference))
 .filter(ts_df["type"] != "A")
)

joined_df = (
 ts_df_A
 .join(ts_df_td, ts_df_A["Aid"] == ts_df_td["id"])
 .select("id", "Ats", "ts", "type", lit(ts_df_A["Ats"] - ts_df_td["ts"]))
)```

To prove this code is more efficient than the previous one, we need to test this on good volume of data.

Comment: I agree, thanks a lot for helping!
I will update the post with a concrete solution and mention the performance when I will test it on a big amount of data!
Cheers!